# finding min and max value in an object like array

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to find a minimum and maximum value from an array

tried various things, but could not find the solution to satisfy my needs

I have an array object like

its values are

```
{
    0:exchange:bitfix

    totaleth:334

    1:exchange:coinbase

    totaleth:6000

    2:exchange:koinex

    totaleth:3000
}
```

now this object like an array, I want to show the minimum and maximum values, based on totaleth field, does any 1 have a solution

I tried various things like map reduce for loop, nothing seems to be working

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: first problem is syntax because this isn't even valid

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share some code. Remember: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service!

Comment: sorry for incomplete question my data is [{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d48","exchange":"Poloniex","totaleth":-338,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.232Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d47","exchange":"Bitrex","totaleth":-227,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.222Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d46","exchange":"Gemini","totaleth":86,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.220Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d45","exchange":"Bitfinex","totaleth":-373,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.219Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed4a9a5b931c3057d44","exchange":"Binance","totaleth":6531,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:36.586Z","__v":0},

Comment: i want to display exchange names with maximum and minimum totaleth

Comment: Please edit this into your question @SukKhoi

Comment: iam coding in vuejs, iam pulling data from axios.get and then pushing the data into this.wheretobuynsell  and on that data i want to find min and max values based on totaleth

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an array of objects, you could reduce the array by taking min and max values.

```js
var array = [{ exchange: 'bitfix', totaleth: 334 }, { exchange: 'coinbase', totaleth: 6000 }, { exchange: 'koinex', totaleth: 3000 }],
    { min, max } = array.reduce(
        (r, o, i) => i
            ? {
                min: r.min.totaleth < o.totaleth ? r.min : o,
                max: r.max.totaleth > o.totaleth ? r.max : o
            }
            : { min: o, max: o },
        undefined
    );
    
console.log('min', min);
console.log('max', max);
```

Comment: thanks for the share, but i have an object which is filled with forloop this.wheretobuynsell.push(dd.data) and there iam pushing data something like this {"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d46","exchange":"Gemini","totaleth":86,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.220Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d45","exchange":"Bitfinex","totaleth":-373,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.219Z","__v":0},                                                                           now i  want to use this.wheretobuynsale object for finding min and max value, i tried to change, but its not working for me with this.wheretobuynsell

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you can use sort function, but remember that it modifies original array.

```
const someArr = [{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d48","exchange":"Poloniex","totaleth":-338,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.232Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d47","exchange":"Bitrex","totaleth":-227,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.222Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d46","exchange":"Gemini","totaleth":86,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.220Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed5a9a5b931c3057d45","exchange":"Bitfinex","totaleth":-373,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:37.219Z","__v":0},{"_id":"5c585ed4a9a5b931c3057d44","exchange":"Binance","totaleth":6531,"dt":"2019-02-04T15:48:36.586Z","__v":0}];

console.log(
  someArr.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.totaleth - b.totaleth;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code worked thanks a lot nina scholz

```js
var array = [{ exchange: 'bitfix', totaleth: 334 }, { exchange: 'coinbase', totaleth: 6000 }, { exchange: 'koinex', totaleth: 3000 }],
    { min, max } = array.reduce(
        (r, o, i) => i
            ? {
                min: r.min.totaleth < o.totaleth ? r.min : o,
                max: r.max.totaleth > o.totaleth ? r.max : o
            }
            : { min: o, max: o },
        undefined
    );
    
console.log('min', min);
console.log('max', max);
```